# Как разместить проект Laravel в GitHub

Tags: php, laravel, github

имеется проект Laravel который предполагается копировать, что-то типа набросок интернет-магазина, с дальнейшим редизайном.

Интересует как правильнее всего будет его разместить в github что бы в случает каких-то обновлений они применялись на все проекты где эта наработка используется? Само собой командой `composer update`

Comment: Не командой `composer update` а `git pull`

Comment: @Alpha речь идет о проектах где использоваться будет наработка

Comment: а почему вы не пользуетесь гуглом для столь тривиальных вещей? Скопируйте ваш заголовок и вставьте его в поисковую строку

Comment: @Alpha что б если кто-то еще загуглит мой заголовок получил ответы с разных мест, ру информации я не увидел в результатах

Comment: первая ссылка https://maxsite.org/page/how-to-put-your-project-on-github-com

Comment: @Alpha там не описано как решается моя проблема